# how to remove characters only from the end of a string?

Tags: python

I have the following code from which I remove `-dev.*` and `-rel.*` from the end,however when I have something like `com-devices.lnx.1.0-dev` it removes from from the beginning and outputs `com` where as I expect it to print `com-devices.lnx`,please see branch3 below...how to remove dev.* only from the end?

```
import re
chars_to_remove = ['-dev.*','-rel.*'] # modify char to remove here
def remove_char(s):
    return re.sub("({})$".format('|'.join(chars_to_remove)), '',  s)

branch1 = 'bt.lnx.2.1-dev.1.0'
branch2 = 'bt.lnx.2.1-rel.1.0'
branch3 = 'com-devices.lnx.1.0-dev'
print remove_char(branch1) # 'bt.lnx.2.1'
print remove_char(branch2) # 'bt.lnx.2.1'
print remove_char(branch3) # should print com-devices.lnx.1.0
```

Comment: The period matches any character. It's kind of GREP 1-0-1.

Comment: You say you want to remove `dev.*` but then you say given input `com-devices.lnx.1.0-dev` you want output `com-devices.lnx`.  But that is not removing `dev.*` it is removing `*-dev`!  So what EXACTLY are your desired inputs and outputs?

Comment: @JohnZwinck - I added my desired output as comments after each print....my existing code works for branch1 and branch2 but fails for branch3,i need the same to work for all

Comment: @RadLexus - how do I make it less greedy?

Comment: @JohnZwinck - I updated quesitons,it should've been `-dev.* and -rel.*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.*` is too broad. If we assume (from your examples) that `-dev` and `-rel` may only be followed with a numeric-only version number, then try this:

```
chars_to_remove = ['-dev[0-9.]*','-rel[0-9.]*']
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you need a regular expression for this. Just `str.rsplit` on `'-'`, limiting it to one split:

```
>>> branch1 = 'bt.lnx.2.1-dev.1.0'
>>> branch2 = 'bt.lnx.2.1-rel.1.0'
>>> branch3 = 'com-devices.lnx.1.0-dev'
>>> branch1.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
'bt.lnx.2.1'
>>> branch2.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
'bt.lnx.2.1'
>>> branch3.rsplit('-', 1)[0]
'com-devices.lnx.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you think that `dev.*` means "dev followed by a period followed by anything" -- which is what it would mean *on the command line* in a [Unix-like environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)).

In a real regular expression, period doesn't mean period, it means "any character", and asterisk doesn't mean "any string of characters", it means "the last pattern, any number of times (including zero times)".

You want

```
pat = re.compile('-(dev|rel)\..*$')
def remove_suffix(x):
  return pat.sub("", x)
```

Comment: Note that when you say "on the command line" the name for it is "shell pattern" or "glob."  Just some words people can search for if they expect `*` to mean "anything" and `?` to mean "one character."